# Bootbox execute request after confirmation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a confirmation pop-up on a link in rails. Since the default css for the browsers confirm: method can't be changed, I decided to use bootbox. ( http://bootboxjs.com/ )

Let's say I have the following link in my rails application

```
= link_to "asd", root_path(), id: "test"
```

The following javascript code opens a pop-up , the result is set correctly, what I need now is to perform the link access if the user approved the confirm.

```
$("#test").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
        // ???
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#test").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
      window.open($(this).attr("href"),"_self");
  });
});
```

I figured it out, it wasn t complicated at all, I'm surprised no one answered :-(